# Why is a quantum quench considered as a quantum analog of a thermodynamic transformation?

Tags: non-equilibrium

In [the paper of A. Silva](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4301), he mentioned that it is possible to characterize a quantum quench, from the perspective of nonequilibrium physics, using work statistics because the quantum quench is observed to resemble a standard thermodynamic transformation. Now, why is the quantum quench considered as a quantum analog of a thermodynamic transformation?